# Query zerando coluna ao aplicar order by - Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, query, order-by

Estou com uma query que ao ordenar ela em ASC ela zera uma coluna da minha tabela, porém se eu ordeno em DESC exibe os valores normalmente.

Essa é a query:

```
SELECT 
`tab_medicamentos`.`id`, `tab_medicamentos`.`classe_terapeutica`, `tab_medicamentos`.`apresentacao`, `tab_medicamentos`.`produto` as `nome`, `tab_medicamentos`.`pmc_18_perc` as `preco`, `tab_medicamentos`.`img` as `imagens`, `tab_medicamentos`.`margem`, `tab_medicamentos`.`margem_desconto`, `tab_medicamentos`.`restrcao_hospitalar` 
FROM 
`tab_medicamentos` 
WHERE 
`classe_terapeutica` LIKE '%M01C0%' ESCAPE '!' 
OR `classe_terapeutica` LIKE '%L01B0%' ESCAPE '!' 
OR `classe_terapeutica` LIKE '%N02A0%' ESCAPE '!' 
OR `classe_terapeutica` LIKE '%N02B0%' ESCAPE '!' 
OR `classe_terapeutica` LIKE '%N01A2%' ESCAPE '!' 
OR `classe_terapeutica` LIKE '%N01B1%' ESCAPE '!' 
OR `classe_terapeutica` LIKE '%M01A1%' ESCAPE '!' 
OR `classe_terapeutica` LIKE '%M02A0%' ESCAPE '!' 
OR `classe_terapeutica` LIKE '%R05A0%' ESCAPE '!' 
OR `classe_terapeutica` LIKE '%A11D4%' ESCAPE '!' 
OR `classe_terapeutica` LIKE '%A03D0%' ESCAPE '!' 
OR `classe_terapeutica` LIKE '%M01A3%' ESCAPE '!' 
OR `classe_terapeutica` LIKE '%B01C1%' ESCAPE '!' 
OR `classe_terapeutica` LIKE '%M03B0%' ESCAPE '!' 
OR `classe_terapeutica` LIKE '%N02C9%' ESCAPE '!' 
ORDER BY `pmc_18_perc` ASC
```

Quando coloco o `ORDER BY ASC` ele zera todos os valores dessa coluna `'pmc_18_perc'`, mas quando ordeno em `DESC` aparece os valores normalmente.

O que pode ser?

Comment: tem certeza que zerou todos ou só nos primeiros registros? porque `ORDER BY ASC` vai trazer os dados começando do "menor", zeros, espaços, etc primeiro... pode ser que os dados preenchidos estejam nos próximos registros, chegou a olhar todo o resultado do `select`?

Comment: não zerou todos os valores, apenas ordenou os que estão com valor "0"  a frente.

Comment: Tenta colocar no WHERE, pmc_18_perc IS NOT NULL

Comment: Esqueci de comentar isso, pois sabia que seria a primeira hipótese. Eu verifiquei no final do resultado, e desde da primeira linha à ultima o valor foi zerado! Nunca vi isso! 
Coloquei o IS NOT NULL e não mudou nada.

Answer (score 0):

Já tentou realizar a ordenação em um nível superior?

Ex:

select 
* from 
(SELECT 
`tab_medicamentos`.`id`, `tab_medicamentos`.`classe_terapeutica`, `tab_medicamentos`.`apresentacao`, `tab_medicamentos`.`produto` as `nome`, `tab_medicamentos`.`pmc_18_perc` as `preco`, `tab_medicamentos`.`img` as `imagens`, `tab_medicamentos`.`margem`, `tab_medicamentos`.`margem_desconto`, `tab_medicamentos`.`restrcao_hospitalar` 
FROM 
`tab_medicamentos` 
WHERE 
`classe_terapeutica` LIKE '%M01C0%' ESCAPE '!' 
OR `classe_terapeutica` LIKE '%L01B0%' ESCAPE '!' 
OR `classe_terapeutica` LIKE '%N02A0%' ESCAPE '!' 
OR `classe_terapeutica` LIKE '%N02B0%' ESCAPE '!' 
OR `classe_terapeutica` LIKE '%N01A2%' ESCAPE '!' 
OR `classe_terapeutica` LIKE '%N01B1%' ESCAPE '!' 
OR `classe_terapeutica` LIKE '%M01A1%' ESCAPE '!' 
OR `classe_terapeutica` LIKE '%M02A0%' ESCAPE '!' 
OR `classe_terapeutica` LIKE '%R05A0%' ESCAPE '!' 
OR `classe_terapeutica` LIKE '%A11D4%' ESCAPE '!' 
OR `classe_terapeutica` LIKE '%A03D0%' ESCAPE '!' 
OR `classe_terapeutica` LIKE '%M01A3%' ESCAPE '!' 
OR `classe_terapeutica` LIKE '%B01C1%' ESCAPE '!' 
OR `classe_terapeutica` LIKE '%M03B0%' ESCAPE '!' 
OR `classe_terapeutica` LIKE '%N02C9%' ESCAPE '!' )  as tmp

order by tmp.pmc_18_perc desc

Comment: Tentei, porém está retornando o seguinte erro: #1054 - Coluna 'tmp.pmc_18_perc' desconhecida em 'order clause'.

Assim... Quando faço a consulta com apenas uma clausula ele faz tudo como esperado, agora quando coloca mais uma clausula ele zera todos os valores... não entendo isso.